# Bluetooth Data Transfer

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying Data send with `Bluetooth` intent service with these codes but i can not send message to device. I am debugging this code but DataSend class elements seems null. How can i fix the problem or how can i write correctly sending message code with using intent service ?

I am calling the fragment this way:

final Intent sendData = new Intent(getActivity(),DataSend.class);

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String s = editText.getText().toString();

             sendData.putExtra("test",s);
        }
    });
```

This is my DataSend service code:

```
public class DataSend extends IntentService{

    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private static final String TAG = "DataTransmissionService";

    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private OutputStream outStream = null;
    private BluetoothDevice device = null;
    private Log log;

    public DataSend() {
        super("DataSend");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        cleanup();
        if (intent != null){

            btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            String pairedDeviceAddress = "38:1B:4B:98:E7:ED";

            try {
                log.d(TAG, pairedDeviceAddress);
                device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(pairedDeviceAddress);
                log.d(TAG, "Device bond state : " + device.getBondState());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.e(TAG, "Invalid address: " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            try {
                btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.e(TAG, "Socket creation failed: " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            try {

                if (!btSocket.isConnected()) {
                    btSocket.connect();
                    log.d(TAG, "Connected");
                } else {
                    log.d(TAG, "Already Connected");  //flow never reaches here for any use case
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.e(TAG, "btSocket.connect() failed : " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            try {
                outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.e(TAG, "Failed to get output stream:" + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            sendData("test");
            //cleanup();   called in onDestroy()

        }

    }

    private void cleanup(){

        try {
            if (outStream != null) {
                outStream.close();
                outStream = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.e(TAG, "Failed to close output stream : " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            if (btSocket != null) {
                btSocket.close();
                btSocket = null;
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.e(TAG, "Failed to close connection : " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
            try {
                final Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
                return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
            }
        }

        return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    }

    private void sendData(String message) {

        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
        log.d(TAG, "Sending : " + message);
        try {
            outStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.e(TAG, "failed to write " + message);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is ``null`` and what does that stop you from doing?

Comment: I put the BreakPoint this line:   sendData.putExtra("test",s); at the my fragment. And i saw all DataSend elements null. So i cant see any log, return value or anything else. I dont understand why

Comment: Do you have a 'BluetoothConnection' anywhere, if you do then it is a simple '.write' command.

Comment: it is here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gcPrydZnDw/ but if i use this i can not send message because i am getting this warning :Fragment: The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. So i can not send message because my main thread busy.

Answer (score 1):

I would initialize a BluetoothConnection with the device you are connected to, and then send data that way. It would look somewhat like this:

```
BluetoothConnection connection = new BluetoothConnection(connectedDevice);

public void sendData(){

    String s = editText.getText().toString();

    byte[] b = s.getBytes();

    connection.write(b);

    //System.out.println("Bytes Sent");
}// end sendData
```

Comment: It is not working on my project. I have a null object error this type of code. Because my bluetoothconnectionservice. java shows this WARNING: The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. So i can not send message because my main thread busy. So if i debug my ConnectedThread null. This is my connection codes: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gcPrydZnDw/

Comment: And this is my old topic for this error so i try to service but i can not find any solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416401/connected-thread-return-null-object

Comment: If you are creating a connection in a background thread you can then pass that connected device to the main thread and then start the connection there. You should not have the actual connection occurring on your main thread.

Comment: How can i do this ? I can not do anything 5 days. If you have a answer or suggestion this post or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416401/connected-thread-return-null-object please help

Comment: On your other post I sent you the BluetoothConnection Class, after you implement that this code will work. My bad not including that in this post as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `startService(sendData);` in order to start the Bluetooth send service? It seems that you are just creating the intent and filling it with data but not starting it.

Comment: I have a another java class to connect bluetooth. And i receive data on the this java class. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gcPrydZnDw/ I have a trouble for main thread so i created DataSend intent service. And while i press the send button, my connection succesfull. But i can not connect with this senData. So how can i do that situation ?

Comment: A mean i use this class https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gcPrydZnDw/ and DataSend service class